# Redirect to m.box.com during obtaining the token. no token response what so ever

Tags: javascript, post, box-api

When I do https://api.box.com/oauth2/token
in order to obtain access token it redirect me to m.box.com !!!

I'm using JavaScript XHR POST, cannot get how come it manages redirect me to https://m.box.com/ !?

Here is my request:

```
Request URL:https://api.box.com/oauth2/token
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:box_visitor_id=511bb5cfe018c0.09915316; country_code=US; box_redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fm.box.com%2F; box_redirect_rm=common_main; z=1pm9dat3tb82gs1s2njrdsocg4; referrer=; __utma=254217048.1806492505.1360770515.1360778764.1360781511.3; __utmb=254217048.14.9.1360786227431; __utmc=254217048; __utmz=254217048.1360770515.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=47569716.1075364291.1360770555.1360781565.1360783878.4; __utmb=47569716.5.10.1360783878; __utmc=47569716; __utmz=47569716.1360783878.4.4.utmcsr=api.box.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/oauth2/authorize; RT=s=1360786281036&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.com%2Fapi%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3Dqpome2tetr5oesmq62tut4brabsd9j1q%26state%3Dauthenticated
Origin:platform://.
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; Touch) AppleWebKit/537.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.10.357 Mobile Safari/537.10+
Form Dataview URL encoded
grant_type:authorization_code
code:mj5wDvMwjbbWBlg2QRsN296OvMS9nsWf
client_id:qpome2tetr5oesmq62tut5brabsd9j1q
client_secret:1bCE76NVOe6c3Ro4mKXXrMqW7BLunib4
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store
Connection:close
Content-Length:174
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 13 Feb 2013 20:11:22 GMT
Server:nginx
```

as you see it doesn't carry any response, instead it redirects me to https://www.box.com and then to https://m.box.com !!
Can some one explain me why?

It is Webworks HTML5 for Blackberry 10.

**UPDATE:**

After detaily looking at Network activity I notices when I have redirect_url as https:// it looks like:

> > GET Request URL:https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=qpome2te3r5oesmq62ttt41bdabsd9j1q&state=authenticated
> >     Request Method:POST
> >     Status Code:302 Found
> >
> > GET Request URL:https://google.com/?state=authenticated&code=S1KrsSQG5XWURvpFV8NrfqkuCpCxo2Z3
> >     Request Method:GET
> >     Status Code:301 Moved Permanently

But when I use URI scheme of any kind: like for example misha:// it looks like:

> > GET Request URL:https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=qpome2te3r5oesmq62tttbbddbsd9j1q&state=authenticated
> >     Request Method:POST
> >     Status Code:200 OK
> >
> > GET Request URL:misha://authorised.html?state=authenticated&code=5h49cfldt0zWy8f8Y4IKewTTr07TFzkJ
> >     Request Headersview source
> >     Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
> >     Status: **CANCELLED**
> >
> > GET Request URL:https://www.box.com/
> >     Request Method:GET
> >     Status Code:302 Found

.....

When I use URI scheme which is registered ive got this:

> > GET Request URL:https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=qpome2te3r5oesmq62tttbbddbsd9j1q&state=authenticated
> >     Request Method:POST
> >     Status Code:200 OK
> >
> > GET Request URL:platform:///authorised.html?state=authenticated&code=l793tAT7eVpl85gvr77ZdnIFHTGYVNsJ
> >     Request Method:GET
> >     Status Code:200

and then in goes for box.com all of a sudden no matter what is do in my authorised.html!??

> > GET Request URL:https://www.box.com/
> >     Request Method:GET
> >     Status Code:302 Found

Comment: You should definitely remove your client id and secret from this sample–people can now access your app.

Comment: No worries it thought about this beforehand, it is all faked up :) also this is test service anyways, going to ditch it after.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue you're running into is making a request from your domain to www.box.com in Javascript. This isn't permitted by [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Yes and No, Yes this case falls under Same Origin Policy, but in same time as you see I have successful request, browser didn't block it, so No this is not an issue. Issue is why box.com redirects my token request to www.box.com?
Also Exactly the same code (started as chrome.exe --disable-web-security) works and obtains access_token properly!

Comment: If it redirecting  assume that it passed XHR check, so question is why box.com redirects me... instead of supplying either meaningful error message or granting a access_token. This is quite a show stopper for me, need help.